# Step through debugging of web app code in Eclipse maven app running on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, tomcat

I am trying to set up eclipse so that I can work on a maven web application which packages as a war file without building the war file and deploying to tomcat webapps manually.

This would also allow me to step through the code. I have installed tomcat 7 and my app deploys there ok and I have pointed eclipse at the installation of tomcat but it does not seem to deploy properly even though the manual deployment works fine.

The issue I get when deploying is that eclipse informs me that tomcat was not able to start.

To deploy my app I am going "servers >> add and remove" and then deploying my application from the available list by moving it into the configured list. After doing this and starting the tomcat server I get the error message.

Can anybody help me with running the app from within eclipse based on the compiled code and not on whats in the war file as ideally my end result would be to be able to step through code I am working on without building the war file first.

Thanks

Comment: What I have found this morning is that the server does actually start (I brought the timeout value down to 20 seconds) and I can access a page but in the progress window the server is still marked as starting, once the time out has been breached tomcat stops and I get the error message "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 20 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.". All that increasing the timeout does is delay the time until the message pops up and tomcat stops.

Comment: I have tried starting a tomcat 5.5 and tomcat 6 server all of which are unpacked to program files and all of which start from the command line with no problems and I get exactly the same error. I have read pretty much every post I can find on this issue and tried all of the fixes but none seem to work, I am running this one windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I finally sorted this out after a few hours of messing around reading numerous posts, so hopefully this answer may help someone else who gets the error message:

"Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds"

Below are the steps I took:

1) Backed up my projects in my work space and then deleted the workspace
2) Recreated the workspace and imported my projects back into it
3) (this bit was crucial for me) - Added a connector to my server.xml on port 8080 as my app was set up to only run with SSL, it seems that eclipse tries to verify your app started by hitting the root of the web app and it couldnt do this due to the SSL connector.

I hope this helps someone out.